# Detect picture-in-picture mode in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, firefox, video.js, picture-in-picture

Hello fellow developpers!

I know firefox has is own implementation of picture-in-picture (pip) and i was wondering if there is any way to detect pip events in firefox using javascript/typescript.

I've started implementing videojs in my angular application. When i click a button i need to open a video in a modal and when entering pip mode i need to hide this modal.

For this i've my own modal component and clicks events. It's working fine on chrome and other browsers but on firefox i can't find a way to detect pip mode and hide the modal.

Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't as Firefox unfortunately hasn't implemented any picture in picture API.

Comment: I'll have to make a special treatment for firefox then, thanks for the answer